# Reading file and storing into variable

Tags: c, string, file, save

I have spent the last 4 or 5 hours on something that is probably quite simple, I have tried many different methods. What I am trying to do is make my program save the end of each line in a saved test file. This would be the players names followed by the shirt number or weight etc. The file is saved in a format like this:

First name is:xxxxxx

Last name is:xxxxx

Date of birth is:xxxxxx

I want my code to be able to just store the xxxxxx in a separate variable so then i can un-encrypt it as only them parts are encrypted.

The code I have got so far is

```
int main()
{
    int dob;
    char lastname[15], *ptr, filename[25], line[40], storage[200], a[15];
    FILE *file;

    printf("Please enter the last name of your player: ");
    scanf("%s", lastname);
    printf("\nPlease enter the date of birth of your player: ");
    scanf("%d", &dob);
    printf("\n\n");
    sprintf(filename, "%s%6d.pat", lastname, dob);
    printf("%s", filename);
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);

    }


    fscanf(file, "%s: %s\n", storage, a);
    printf("%s %s", storage, a);
```

I am now currently trying to use this piece of code to the get the last string after the : then apply a small decryption to it, but i seem to get an infinite loop of just the name after the first line.

```
   do
    {
        if(sscanf(line,"%*[^:]:%19s",s)==1)
        {  
            for(i = 0; i < slen; i++) /*encrypting firstname*/
            {
                slen = strlen(s);
                s[i] = (char)((s[i] - 'a' - 4) % 26 + 'a');
                if(s == '\0')
                {
                    break;
                }        
            }    
            printf("%s",s);
            slen = strlen(s);
            slen--;

        }
    }while(slen > 0);
```

Comment: could you explain what part is missing ?

Comment: Ill add what I have now and what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `sscanf` function -

```
char s[20];
if(sscanf(line,"%*[^:]:%19s",s)==1){          //check return of sscanf
 /*                  %*[^:] will read string till ':' and discard it     */
         printf("%s",s);
}
```

This will store your desired string in `s`.

**Note** - Data in your file should in form as you show in question.

If you want data even outside loop then use a 2-d `char` array instead . Increment index of array in loop as you read new data from file.

### EDIT-

Dont use uninitialized variable `slen` before calculating string length . You can re-write your code as -

```
    int i=0;
    if(sscanf(line,"%*[^:]:%19s",s)==1)
    {  
        slen = strlen(s);
        while(i<slen)/*encrypting firstname*/
        {
            //slen = strlen(s);
            s[i] = (char)((s[i] - 'a' - 4) % 26 + 'a');
            if(s == '\0')
            {
                break;
            }       
             i++; 
        }    
        printf("%s",s);           
        slen--;
    }
```

Comment: I see this is saving all of the headers into the same string, this would normally be really good (much better than what I had), but I need to same how be able to de-crypt the information which means knowing how many letters are in each word. The only way i know how to do this is to find the string lenght and then make the if statement loop that many times -1.

Comment: @Thecube  This is has to be done in loop where you read from file . The string you represented using `xxxxxxx` wll be saved in `s` . Now after saving all such strings , you will need to de-crypt as you desire. And finding string length , `strlen(s)` will directly give you length of `xxxxxxx` string saved in it .

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < s; i++);

{if(sscanf(line,"%*[^:]:%19s",s)==1){  
    
printf("%s",s);

slen = strlen(s);

}

}` Is how i am currently trying to use a loop to do each word one by one, but getting an error message saying i am comparing pointer and integer

Comment: In loop condition `i < s` , you compare `i` with arrat `s`  . You should compare with `slen` . But as `slen` will be `uninitialized before you do this operation , use a `do-while` loop .

Comment: I have done a do while loop with the statement being while slen > 0, and decremented it for each loop, but the statement is in an infinite loop where what its looping is not output correctly either. I have currently got it to encrypt all but the last letter, and then it just gets struck in an infinite loop

Comment: I have added it into the main post

Comment: @Thecube I have made the changes .

Comment: That is working except that for the last letter of each word  after encrypting is an _ and its skipping not showing the last chacters